# Magento migration error 1.9.3.7 to 2.2.3

Tags: magento2-migration-tool

[ERROR]: Class accesscontrol/entity_attribute_backend_customergroups does not exist but mentioned in: eav_attribute.backend_model for attribute_id=198

I have added this to class-map.xml under folder 1.9.3.7

`...
<classmap xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xs:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../class-map.xsd">
    <rename>
        <from>accesscontrol/entity_attribute_backend_customergroups</from>
    <to />
    </rename
...`

But the error continues

I am running:

php70 bin/magento migrate:data -r -a ~/m2/vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/opensource-to-opensource/1.9.3.7/config.xml

Answer (score 0):

Please back up of Magento 1 database.
Then remove that 198 number attribute id via database.
And run Migration again.

Hope it will help you.

Comment: I would like to know why class-map.xml is not working. It should work for further classes that can not be erased.
Thank you!

Comment: Are you using any tool for migration?

Comment: Magento database migration tool, this is where it requests to comment on class-map.xml, but it does not work.